# ASP.NET convert IQueryable to List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got the following code with the following error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Linq.IQueryable<Receptura_v4.Models.ReceptDTO>'` to
>   `'Receptura_v4.Models.ReceptDTO'`. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)

Any ideas how to solve it?

```
public ReceptDTO GetReceptForUser(string userId)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    { 
        var q = from r in db.Recipes where r.UserId == userId select new ReceptDTO
            {
                 RecipeID = r.RecipeID,
                 Title = r.Title,
                 Portion = r.Portion,
                 Time = r.Time,
                 Category = r.Category,
                 Preparation = r.Preparation,
                 Difficulty = r.Difficulty,
                 Views = 0,
                 Price = r.Price,
                 Date = DateTime.Now,
                 UserId = userId
            };
        return q;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that your return type and what you are returning do not match. Your return type is `ReceptDTO` and you are returning a type of `IQueryable<ReceptDTO>`

You can return the a `ReceptDTO` object by sending back the First Object from the `IQueryable`

```
public ReceptDTO GetReceptForUser(string userId)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    { 
        var q = from r in db.Recipes where r.UserId == userId select new ReceptDTO
            {
                 RecipeID = r.RecipeID,
                 Title = r.Title,
                 Portion = r.Portion,
                 Time = r.Time,
                 Category = r.Category,
                 Preparation = r.Preparation,
                 Difficulty = r.Difficulty,
                 Views = 0,
                 Price = r.Price,
                 Date = DateTime.Now,
                 UserId = userId
            };
        return q.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

If you need to return a list, you can change your method return type and return a list of ReceptDTO

```
public List<ReceptDTO> GetReceptForUser(string userId)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    { 
        var q = from r in db.Recipes where r.UserId == userId select new ReceptDTO
            {
                 RecipeID = r.RecipeID,
                 Title = r.Title,
                 Portion = r.Portion,
                 Time = r.Time,
                 Category = r.Category,
                 Preparation = r.Preparation,
                 Difficulty = r.Difficulty,
                 Views = 0,
                 Price = r.Price,
                 Date = DateTime.Now,
                 UserId = userId
            };
        return q.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
var q = from r in db.Recipes where r.UserId == userId select new ReceptDTO
                {
                     RecipeID = r.RecipeID,
                     Title = r.Title,
                     Portion = r.Portion,
                     Time = r.Time,
                     Category = r.Category,
                     Preparation = r.Preparation,
                     Difficulty = r.Difficulty,
                     Views = 0,
                     Price = r.Price,
                     Date = DateTime.Now,
                     UserId = userId
                };
```

Asssigns `q` with a `IQueryable<ReceptDTO>`

While your prototype expects a return type of a single `ReceptDTO`:

```
public ReceptDTO GetReceptForUser(string userId)
```

If you want to return an `IQueryable<ReceptDTO>` then change your prototype to:

```
public IQueryable<ReceptDTO> GetReceptForUser(string userId)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        { 
            var q = from r in db.Recipes where r.UserId == userId select new ReceptDTO
                {
                     RecipeID = r.RecipeID,
                     Title = r.Title,
                     Portion = r.Portion,
                     Time = r.Time,
                     Category = r.Category,
                     Preparation = r.Preparation,
                     Difficulty = r.Difficulty,
                     Views = 0,
                     Price = r.Price,
                     Date = DateTime.Now,
                     UserId = userId
                };
            return q;
        }
    }
```

If you want to return the first Item from your query then add a `FirstOrDefault()` :

```
    public ReceptDTO GetReceptForUser(string userId)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        { 
            var q = from r in db.Recipes where r.UserId == userId select new ReceptDTO
                {
                     RecipeID = r.RecipeID,
                     Title = r.Title,
                     Portion = r.Portion,
                     Time = r.Time,
                     Category = r.Category,
                     Preparation = r.Preparation,
                     Difficulty = r.Difficulty,
                     Views = 0,
                     Price = r.Price,
                     Date = DateTime.Now,
                     UserId = userId
                };
            return q.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```